# How to find out the right ldap parameters

Tags: java, url, active-directory, ldap

I'm currently working on a small project with Active Directory and some LDAP stuff...
I try to connect to the LDAP server and it always gives me the same error:

```
[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

As much as I know this means that the credentials are wrong, but I'm 100% sure that they're right!
Could it be that I forgot a parameter?

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://libertycity.ch:389/dc=libertycity,dc=ch");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=" + username + ",ou=Users");
env.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectSID");

DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

I think my code looks right, or did I miss something? What could be the problem and how can I find that out?

Comment: muffin, I am getting exact same error as you. Customer is entering correct credentials and their DN looks good. In my testing environment, I never got this error! What is the fix in your case? at least, that would give me some clue. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: It's been an error I've had a while ago, but I remember that the problem wasn't the credentials...
Your problem is probably that you use a wrong "OU" somewhere during the authentication (for example, "ou=Users" could be incomplete because you forgot to add a domain in the end, or something else...)
I would not focus too much on the credentials, they are probably right. Instead try out other paths (so everything with "ou=") and that might help ;)

Comment: Thanks muffin for replying. I'll check for any wrong search bases.

Comment: I have an error similar to you both which I refer it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166646/spring-security-authentication-using-active-directory-failed. I connect to the Ldap via JXplorer, so I'm sure that the settings are correct. But I can't login to the project with users that have already declared in Ldap and I got same error. How can I inform about the right "OU" to use in my configuration? I'll be wonder if you can help me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The value, "data 52e", provided in the error implies the bind failed due to:
Returns when username is valid but password/credential is invalid.

http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors

Comment: the link is 404 atm

Comment: Thanks. Fixed Link.

Comment: In my case, I had to use `domain\user` instead of `user` because I was connecting to a different domain.

Answer (score 11):

This problem may also arise if the full domain is not included with the user name.

Set the security principal as `username@domain`.

```
InitialLdapContext ldapContext = new InitialLdapContext();
ldapContext.addToEnvironment(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
ldapContext.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
ldapContext.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userId + "@mydomain.com");
ldapContext.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);                  
ldapContext.addToEnvironment(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + ldapHost + ":" + ldapPort);
```

Comment: thank you! I just wrote a whole big question, was ready to post it, and saw this question pop up in related questions. All I was missing, was the "@mydomain.com". Now it works :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

I have had the issues trying to secure a connection from wildfly to an Microsoft  active directory server, the main problem is not knowing what connection string should be.
If you install the 'Active Directory Explorer' from Sysinternals took kit provided by Microsoft.  Search for the object that you wish to bind to, a 'Path:' setting will be displayed. That is the string of values that you need to quote in the argument to the Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL value.
In my case the path string was of the format

> CN=Fred Blogs,OU=XXX Users,DC=foo-bar,DC=com,xxx.foo-bar.com:389 [xxx.foo-bar.com]]

The required argument would be

"CN=Fred Blogs,OU=XXX Users,DC=foo-bar,DC=com"

Please note that spaces are very important

Answer (score 1):

LDAP error code 49 indicates "Invalid credentials" which means the password you sent to the LDAP server was not correct.

Comment: The ldap result code "49" implies invalid credentials. Could be the password or distinguished name.

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory: Check your Domain Containers.

I had the same error working on a migration from eDirectory to Active Directory, the user name and password seemed to be correct but for some reason i was still getting the "52e" error which indicates the password is not correct.

I had to add the DC's (Domain Containers) to the principal to make it work:

This wasn't working:

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN="+username+",OU=Users,OU=Org,OU=ETC");
```

Adding the DCs: (This worked for me)

```
 env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN="+username+",OU=Users,OU=Org,OU=ETC,DC=yourorg,DC=com");
```

This solved the problem to me for Active Directory.

Something that really helped my to solve this issue was trying to bind using the linux ldapbind / ldapsearch command https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/network.920/a96579/comtools.htm.

if you make it work from the OS using ldapbind / ldapsearch commands then you will know what exact parameters you should use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

DirContext ldapContext;

```
    Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
      ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
      //ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://societe.fr:389");
      ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://10.112.115.14:389");
      ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
      ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "vmware-china@viewconnection.com");
      ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "ca$hc0w");
      //ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
      //ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "simple");
      ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);

      System.out.println(ldapContext);

      // Create the search controls         
      SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();

      //Specify the attributes to return
      String returnedAtts[]={"sn","givenName", "samAccountName", "mail"};
      searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

      //Specify the search scope
      searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

      //specify the LDAP search filter
      String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(mail=*))";

      //Specify the Base for the search
      String searchBase = "DC=VIEWCONNECTION, DC=COM";
      //initialize counter to total the results
      int totalResults = 0;

   // Search for objects using the filter
      NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ldapContext.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);

    //Loop through the search results
      while (answer.hasMoreElements())
      {
        SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();

        totalResults++;

        System.out.println(">>>" + sr.getName());
        Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>" + attrs.get("samAccountName"));
      }

      System.out.println("Total results: " + totalResults);
      ldapContext.close();
```

Comment: after several times try, this code works. the key is you shall understand the arguments, like searchBase, searchFilter, CN, DC etc...