# Spring security authentication using active directory failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I've been working on a spring web application project in our company. It used to authenticate users using database, but recently we decided to use our active directory server as a means of authentication party. So, we changed the spring-security.xml to the code below:

```
<http auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/Content/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/Desktop/New_Them/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/App/Index" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/App/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/clc/ClcLogPhon/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/App/Login" />
        <remember-me key="myAppKey" />
        <session-management
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas">
        </session-management>
        <csrf />
        <headers>
            <xss-protection />
        </headers>
    </http>
<beans:bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <beans:constructor-arg
            value="ldap://192.168.1.199:389/DC=myDomain,DC=org" />
        <beans:property name="userDn"
            value="CN=myUsername,CN=Users,DC=myDomain,DC=org" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="myPassword" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <beans:property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:value>uid={0},ou=users</beans:value>
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <beans:constructor-arg value="ou=groups" />
                <beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="ou" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>
```

And the web application starts up well. But when I want to login with users which declared before in the active directory, the error below is occurred:

```
DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
DEBUG ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG LdapAuthenticationProvider - Processing authentication request for user: m.fazel
DEBUG BindAuthenticator - Attempting to bind as uid=m.fazel,ou=users,dc=myDomain,dc=org
DEBUG DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource - Removing pooling flag for user uid=m.fazel,ou=users,dc=myDomain,dc=org
DEBUG BindAuthenticator - Failed to bind as uid=m.fazel,ou=users: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1];
DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'sessionRegistry'
DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'logoutSuccessHandler'
DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@560d9ba6
DEBUG TokenBasedRememberMeServices - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.
DEBUG TokenBasedRememberMeServices - Cancelling cookie
DEBUG SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler - Redirecting to /spring_security_login?login_error
DEBUG DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to '/hafizApps/spring_security_login?login_error'
```

As you can see debug result above, it caused due to Ldap error:

```
LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

However, I have already connected to the server with [JXplorer](http://jxplorer.org/). There is no alternative error in ldap connection settings. And also the test user which I trying to connect with (i.e. m.fazel), is already declared in ldap as you can see in the figure below:

[image: JXplorer: ldap users]

**After @jeemster edit:**

However, uid was exactly what was written in [spring security ldap authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html).I change the spring-security.xml just like jeemster said and put cn={0},ou=test instead of uid={0},ou=users. The bean with id="ldapAuthProvider" is changed to the bean demonstrated below:

```
<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <beans:property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:value>CN={0},OU=test</beans:value>
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <beans:constructor-arg value="ou=groups" />
                <beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="ou" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>
```

Also, I create a new user in the test group and named it alialavi. The new user which created in the ldap was shown in the figure below.

[image]

As demonstrated in the above figure that capture from JXplorer, the distinguished name for the new user is:

```
cn=alialavi,ou=test,dc=hafiz-co,dc=org
```

But after the web application starts up, I see this error again in login page:

```
DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
DEBUG ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG LdapAuthenticationProvider - Processing authentication request for user: alialavi
DEBUG BindAuthenticator - Attempting to bind as cn=alialavi,ou=test,dc=hafiz-co,dc=org
DEBUG DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource - Removing pooling flag for user cn=alialavi,ou=test,dc=hafiz-co,dc=org
DEBUG BindAuthenticator - Failed to bind as CN=alialavi,OU=test: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]
DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@4481f947
DEBUG TokenBasedRememberMeServices - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.
```

Again it caused error with the new distinguishedName:

```
cn=alialavi,ou=test,dc=hafiz-co,dc=org
```

Although both distinguishedName is the same, the error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

I would first try changing:

```
uid={0},ou=users
```

to

```
cn={0},ou=users
```

Normally, uid is not a value within Microsoft Active Directory.

However, the error:

```
data 52e
```

Returns AFIK, when username is valid but password/credential is invalid.

Finally, it appears from what is posted, that

```
m.fazel
```

Is the samAccountName and not the cn or uid of the user. The LDAP DN being used for the bind appears to be:

```
uid=m.fazel,ou=users,dc=myDomain,dc=org
```

Does this user appears in the directory?

-jim

Comment: thank you in advance for your response, I did what you've said in your response and edited the question after that. you can see the result in the new update. I totally agree with you about cn instead of uid. however, as I said in the edited version it is just what was written in spring security reference. I'll wonder if you see the new update in my question.